# npm audit find vulnerability in package yarn why doesn't find

Tags: yarnpkg

`npm audit` (and Github) find this vulnerability:

```
# Run  npm update macaddress --depth 5  to resolve 1 vulnerability

  Critical        Command Injection

  Package         macaddress

  Dependency of   css-loader [dev]

  Path            css-loader > cssnano > postcss-filter-plugins > uniqid >
                  macaddress

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/654
```

Not only does `yarn audit` not find this vulnerability, `yarn why` isn't aware of such a dependency:

```
> yarn why macaddress
yarn why v1.12.3
[1/4] Why do we have the module "macaddress"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
error We couldn't find a match!
Done in 0.66s
```

It also doesn't find `uniqid` however it does find `postcss-filter-plugins`.

Can anybody explain why `yarn` and `npm` seem to have a different idea on what's in the dependency tree?

Comment: did you try yarn audit?

Comment: @Santosh, as I wrote `yarn audit` doesn't find the vulnerability.

Comment: Can someone confirm or deny that yarn audit and npm audit use the same database of vulnerabilities. The only answer I have found is this one: https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/auditjs/issues/73. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yarn audit and npm audit, both works based on their locked file, package-lock.json for npm and yarn.lock for yarn.

If you want the same results, then both the files should be updated. You need to run both npm install and yarn install commands to get updated lock files.

At present, it looks like only one of them is updated and the other is outdated.